# geth account import in gethjs console

Tags: geth-debugging

I can´t execute geth account import command in gethjs console. What is the comand equivalent?? any help??

[image]

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the command `geth account import <key>` is a bash command line, you should using on your windows terminal not on the geth js console.

Comment: You are true thx men ;D